# Odoo: Duplicated BOM Lines after update of BOM by CSV

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I am using Odoo 11.0 and I have created a kit BOM with two compoenents through by using the CSV import using the following structure:.

"id","product_tmpl_id/id","bom_line_ids/product_id/id","type"

If I reimport the CSV I still have one BOM but it has now four components. Not good! The obvious solution is to add an external ID to the BOM line item using "bom_line_ids/id" but that doesn't seem to work. If I use a column for the external ID the import will complain that the external ID "mrp_bom_line" with that ID does not exist. That is obviously true: I am just trying to create it..The obvious natural keys product+sequence or product+bom_line_product don't seem to work either.

If I look at the export it uses "__export__.mrp_bom_line_45_5351bb5a" which I assume is the internal identifier. This is not available in the during the update.

Any ideas how to do an update of a BOM?

Comment: That's more a functional question and belongs into the [Odoo forums](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1). But i think new external IDs can only be "created" while importing the model which is imported, or short if it's the plain column with header "id". Your idea "bom_line_ids/id" won't work cause Odoo won't create an external ID there but instead searches for an existing one. So either use divided csv files per model or try to import by using the external API.

Comment: I see what you mean: In theory I could create a list of "empty" BOMs first, and then using a different file to add the BOM lines to the empty BOMs. In practice this won't work because there is not independent import for BOM lines and hence no import.
This seems to be sucha common use case that I consider this a bug.

Comment: It's a feature ;-)

Comment: @fhossfel Usually what I would do is create a separate list view for BOM Lines and import the BOM Lines separately from the main BOM. You can probably still use the same spreadsheet if you manually change the headers on the import screen.

Comment: Okay, I can try to do that. But this has still one drawback: I can't delete BOM lines with that approach. If they are not part of the "new" Excel sheet I assume they won't get touched at all - remaining there undefinitely.